# Eclipse cannot remember screen

Tags: eclipse, editor, mageia

After installing new version of Eclipse, Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) Build id: 20190917-1200, workspace cannot anymore remember screen, where it were when closing. It always opens on screen 1 on left. Size of window works ok. Previous version has worked ok.
I'm using Mageia 7 with Gnome desktop.

Comment: Do you still have the problem after switching to a new workspace? Is this plain Eclipse without additional plug-ins?

Comment: It does not matter, which workspace I use. Same behaviour. I'm maybe using only javascript-2019-09 -plugins

Comment: Are you talking about physical displays/monitors or virtual desktop screens that you can switch between and are displayed on the same display/monitor?

Comment: physical displays

Comment: The window location and size are saved in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`. Am not aware on a change between Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12) and 2019-09 (4.13); maybe an issue of Mageia. Did you check if the issue has been reported to Eclipse or to Mageia?

Comment: I cannot find anything about window or location on that workbench.xmi-file. File exists and size of 249k. I have tried to find this from both Eclipse & Mageia, no success

Comment: Should be the first match of `height="` in the `workbench.xmi` file: `x="..." y="..." width="..." height="..."`.

Comment: Sorry - it's in there and says now when eclipse is on right screen: x="26" y="23" width="448" height="81"